# Error with align equation

Tags: beamer, align

I am getting an error while using beamer that there is a missing }. I can't see where the error is since it compiles fine. Any help much appreciated.

```
    \begin{align}\label{gs_diff_homog_3}
\begin{bmatrix} \hat a(\omega, x_3) \\ \hat b(\omega,x_3) \end{bmatrix} &= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \chi_1(\omega,x_3) & \chi_2(\omega,x_3) \\ \chi_3(\omega,x_3) & \chi_4(\omega,x_3) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \chi_1(\omega,0) & \chi_2(\omega,0) \\ \chi_3(\omega,0) & \chi_4(\omega,0) \end{bmatrix}^{-1}}_\textrm{$\mathbf{P_{\omega}}(0,x_3)$} \\ &\times\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \chi_1(\omega,0) & \chi_2(\omega,0) \\ \chi_3(\omega,0) & \chi_4(\omega,0) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix}}_\textrm{$[\hat a(\omega,0),\hat b(\omega,0)]^{T}$}. \nonumber
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>

Comment: please always post a complete (small) test document that reproduces the error.

Comment: why are you using `\textrm{$....$}` in subscripts rather than using math mode directly????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subscripts should always be braced `_{...}` .  (Don't rely on the fact that some font commands sometimes work unbraced.)

Here though, `\textrm` should not be used at all:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{zzz}

    \begin{align}\label{gs_diff_homog_3}
\begin{bmatrix} \hat a(\omega, x_3) \\
 \hat b(\omega,x_3) \end{bmatrix} &= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \chi_1(\omega,x_3) & \chi_2(\omega,x_3) \\
 \chi_3(\omega,x_3) & \chi_4(\omega,x_3) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \chi_1(\omega,0) & \chi_2(\omega,0) \\
 \chi_3(\omega,0) & \chi_4(\omega,0) \end{bmatrix}^{-1}}_{\mathbf{P_{\omega}}(0,x_3)} \\
 &\times\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \chi_1(\omega,0) & \chi_2(\omega,0) \\
 \chi_3(\omega,0) & \chi_4(\omega,0) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\
 c_2 \end{bmatrix}}_{\hat a(\omega,0),\hat b(\omega,0)]^{T}}. \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```